# Regex test not working on Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code doesn't give any output. I think the expression might not be compatible with Javascript, it was working properly with PHP. I can't see the mistake anywhere else.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#saatjanimi").blur(function() 
    {
        var input = $(this);
        var reg = /^([-,.'\s\p{L}]*\s+[-,.'\s\p{L}]*)+$/;

        if (!input.val().length || !reg.test(input.val()))
        {
            alert("asd");
            input.after("Avalduse täitja nime lahter peab sisaldama täisnime.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: JS regex does not support Unicode category classes like `\p{L}`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Post that as an answer